# Celery task method is not getting called

Tags: python, django, celery

I have the following method call & particular method in a Python Django web application. (Please note that I am not that much familiar with python, Django or celery)

Method as follows :

```
@shared_task(bind=True, default_retry_delay=10, max_retries=3, ignore_results=False)
def push_sns_message(self, sns_alias, message, target_arn):
    """
    Celery task
    """
    logger.debug("########## Hit the Celery Task ###############")
    print "########## Hit the celery ###########"
    connection = sns_connections[sns_alias]
    return connection.publish(message=message, target_arn=target_arn)
```

Method Call as follows:

```
print "########## Calling to celery ###########"
push_sns_message.s(self.sns_connection, json.dumps(wrapper[0]), self.sns_arn)
```

The issue is whenever I run application, it comes to push_sns_message.s() but doesn't go inside it. I can see the print

> "########## Calling to celery ###########"

but cannot see following print and also other lines also are not called

> "########## Hit the celery ###########"

Please explain this behavior.

Comment: May `push_sns_message.s(self.sns_connection, json.dumps(wrapper[0]), self.sns_arn)` contain an `s` that's not supposed to be there?

Comment: @rakwaht Actually this code snippet is from a legacy application and I am trying to fix a bug of it. I searched a lot what is meant by this s. Unfortunately I have no clear idea about it. Can you please explain why you suggest like above ?

Comment: check calling method name push_sns_message.s added extra .s

Comment: @Prabhav You mean me to remove the .s ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a few potential suggestions in the case that the other answer does not help.

First, do you have the celery worker running? If not, the task will be queued up, but not executed until the worker is ready to receive the task. You can simply call the function (without the .s) and the function should execute as a regular function.

Second, the ".s" is a signature, but is not actually called without "apply_async". Try called the function like this:

```
push_sns_message.s(self.sns_connection, json.dumps(wrapper[0]), self.sns_arn).apply_async()
```

or like this:

```
push_sns_message.s(self.sns_connection, json.dumps(wrapper[0]), self.sns_arn).delay()
```

Hopefully this will help, but here's the [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/calling.html) that you would need to further investigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Log will show up in the worker log of celery not in the standard log of django

If you want to debug it have a look @ rdb for celery
http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.contrib.rdb.html#usage