# Don't "s()" and "si()" work properly in Django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, celery, django-celery-results

I have **`add()` task** in `tasks.py` in Django as shown below. *I use **Celery 5.2.7** and [**django-celery-results**](https://github.com/celery/django-celery-results) in Django on Windows 11:

```py
# "store/tasks.py"

from celery import shared_task

@shared_task
def add(x, y): # Here
    return x + y
```

Then, I called `add.delay(3, 4)` in `test()` in `views.py` as shown below:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .tasks import add
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    add.delay(3, 4) # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

Then, I could properly get the result below:

```
Task store.tasks.add[...] succeeded in 0.06s: 7 # Here
```

But, when calling `add.s(3, 4)` and `add.si(3, 4)` in `test()` as shown below, nothing were displayed:

```py
# "store/views.py"

from .tasks import add
from django.http import HttpResponse

def test(request):

    add.s(3, 4) # Here
    add.si(3, 4) # Here

    return HttpResponse("Test")
```

So, don't `s()` and `si()` work properly in Django?

Comment: These are put in a queue, and eventually a worker, so another process, will run these, and print the result.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Celery task method is not getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49574020/celery-task-method-is-not-getting-called)

Answer (score 1):

The [**`.s(…)`** method <sup>[celery-doc]</sup>](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#example) creates a *signature*: it is basically an object with data to specify what function to call, and with which parameters. It however does *not* schedule the task, nor does it evaluate it in the method itself.

As for the [**`.si()`** <sup>[celery-doc]</sup>](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/canvas.html#immutability) also creates a signature, but an immutable one.

You can schedule the tasks, for example with:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

from .tasks import add


def test(request):

    add.s(3, 4).apply_async()
    add.si(3, 4).apply_async()

    return HttpResponse('Test')
```

This will however not return the result, it will return a task. You can wait for these tasks to return, or for example save the task handler in the database.

It will thus add the task to the queue, and eventually a worker will pick it up and evaluate it.

Comment: With `apply_async()`, it actually returns **the value 7**. Thank you.